# UI freezes with multiple http calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Please find below the `angularjs` factory method to call http request:

```
var HttpService = angular.module("HttpService",[]);

HttpService.factory("HttpServiceFactory",['$http', '$q', '$location', '$rootScope' ,function($http, $q, $location, $rootScope){
  return {
    getData: function(url, headers, bOnErrorRedirect, bShowInPageError, params){
      var headerParam = {'Accept':'application/json'};
      if(headers !== undefined || headers !== null){
        headerParam = $.extend(headerParam, headers);
      }

      var updatedParams = {'TimeStamp':new Date().getTime()};
      updatedParams = $.extend(params, updatedParams);

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get(url,{
        headers: headerParam,
          params : updatedParams
      }).success(function(successResponse){
          if(successResponse){          
            var responseJSON = angular.fromJson(successResponse);
            if(responseJSON && responseJSON.messages && responseJSON.messages.length){
              //Process Error
            }else{
              deferred.resolve(successResponse);
            }
          }else{
            deferred.resolve(successResponse);
          } 
      }).error(function(errorResponse , status){
        //Process Error
          console.error("status here:: "+status);           
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }      
}]);
```

And I am calling this method in controller with all required dependencies as below:

```
HttpServiceFactory.getData(args.sURL,null,false,true,args.oQueryParams).then(function(response){                        
                        scope.bDataLoading = false;                     
                        // process data                 
                    })
                    .catch(function(oResponse) {
                        scope.bDataLoading = false;
                        scope.bDisplayError = true;                     
                        // process error
                    });
```

Here everything works fine. But the issue is when I've multiple `http` calls on a page, the UI freezes and does not allow to interact till the request has been processed.

For example, on a page I am displaying 2 `angular-ui-grid` based on user's selected criteria by input box and calendar control. In such case, the UI freezes until both grids have been displayed or error message has been displayed.

During `http` service call, user can not do anything but simply wait to finish the request.

**How do I resolve the issue of UI freezing ? Is it a true async behavior ? If not, what am I missing to achieve correct async behavior ?**

Comment: How big is the data set and column count for grids? According to this: http://www.ag-grid.com/why-the-world-needed-another-angularjs-grid/  ui-grid may not be feasible in certain scenarios.

Comment: @FDIM - Thanks for the comment. `angular-ui-grid` works just fine for my project. I think the issue is with handling multiple `http` calls.

Comment: well, then you can profile and see which function stalls rendering. It's easy with chrome